# Multiple Sequences RNN/LSTM in Keras

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have multiple sequences of varying length. Each has about 9 features. I want to predict the values of all the continuous features at time t+1. The data is in a list of length 2000 (so, 2000 total sequences). How could one do this in Keras?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(None,9)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
```

This is all I really have, but I'm getting some size mismatches. Any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to pad your sequences to uniform length using the pad_sequences() utility in Keras's Preprocessing suite.

Comment: just to understand the question.
Currently, you have 2000 rows with 9 columns?

Comment: not quite, I have 2000 different sequences. So the first could have a length of 150, the second could be 128, the third could be 163, etc.

Comment: You figure out a good way of handling this? I've got the same issue